# My object is not coming to the desired position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a new developer in Unity and trying to make a mobile game. I have an object in my scene and I want to move it to the position where my finger goes. I can achieve this, but the object is lagging a bit behind. I have tried all the ways I know, but the object always comes from behind where I touch. Please help me.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 _mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Vector3 _worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(_mousePos);
    _worldPos.y = 0f;
    transform.position = _worldPos;
}
```